# parsing xml javascript- Display tags as text

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

Suppose the xml is :

```
<title><script>alert("Hello");</script></title>
```

The below code returns null.

```
txt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I want txt to have the value below and i want to display it as text.

```
<script>alert("Hello");</script>
```

How do i parse the xml?

The xml can be like this too :

```
<title><sample>alert("Hello");</sample></title>
```

I just want the entire content within the title tag as text irrespective of the content of the title tag

Comment: is that your entire xml doc? if so, try adding a this to the beginning of it: <?xml version="1.0"?>

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xml = "<title><sample>alert(1);</sample></title>";
if (window.DOMParser)
{
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");

    var data = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title");
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        document.write("<div class='script'>")
        document.write("&lt;"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeName+">"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("sample")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue+"&lt;/"+xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[i].childNodes[0].nodeName+">");
        document.write("</div>")
    }
}
</script>
```

Notice the white space in script tag "< script>", this will avoid the execution of the script that is inside it, if you remove this white space then the script will be executed and output will be shown in alert instead of document body.

Also notice the backslash '\' I used in xml string, this is because of the fact that JavaScript ends at  tag, so adding a backslash will make it the part of string.

Comment: This is not what i want. The xml can be like this too :<title><sample>alert("Hello");</sample></title> I just want the entire content within the <title> tag as text

Comment: sorry this is not what i want.I want a more generic solution so that the title tag can contain anything.For eg : <title>hello</title> or <title><hello>alert;</title>.Probably i should try var txt =xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0] and then use xml serializer to convert object to string.